# Possible cause and solution for this warning

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Warning : Cannot update a component (`X`) while rendering a different component (`Y`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `Y`, follow the stack trace as described in :

Answer (score 6):

There are suggestions on this document. It looks like the same warning. 
[doc door](https://zh-hant.reactjs.org/blog/2020/02/26/react-v16.13.0.html)

It is supported to call setState during render, but only for the same component. If you call setState during a render on a different component, you will now see a warning:

```
Warning: Cannot update a component from inside the function body of a different component.
```

This warning will help you find application bugs caused by unintentional state changes. In the rare case that you intentionally want to change the state of another component as a result of rendering, you can wrap the setState call into useEffect.

Comment: putting the setState in the useEffect ended the warning for me. But i wonder if its still a good way to do it.